# 302 redirect and referrer information

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-302

i need to do a 302 redirect to a partner company domain.  they want to track all of their incoming traffic.

will my index.html 302'd page not pass referrer info?

how do i configure this page to pass the referrer info, if not.

Answer (score 4):

The referer is sent by the browser, and there is not much you can do about that.

If they really want to track which users came from your website, a solution would be to add a parameter to the URL you are redirecting to.

For instance, instead of redirecting to

```
http://www.otherserver.com/index.php
```

You would redirect to something like :

```
http://www.otherserver.com/index.php?from=mysite
```

But, of course, this means more work, both on your side and theirs...

Comment: why does that mean more work? Should i use a 301 instead? Considering this will in place for a year as a pilot program? then adjust the location after that time if need be? here is what i envision my index.asp page would look like: <%@ Language=VBScript %> <% ' Permanent redirection Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently" Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.partnercompany.com/specificpage.asp?from=mysite" Response.End %> <html> <head> <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"> </head> </html> does that look ok?

Comment: It means a bit more work because you'll have to pass an additional parameters -- and the other end will have to understand it to identify your site (which means modifying their existing systems, which is now based on Referer)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple index page telling the user it's being redirected. **Instead of** using 302 http redirect, you can use the following script to redirect the user. This will result in the referer being set to your domain.

```
<script>
window.location = "https://www.someplace.nl/";
</script>
```